# How to read data passed by --data in Curl in python?

Tags: python, http, curl, flask, https

I am trying to read data passed using `curl` `-d` option in python.

The data is in JSON and I tried using 
 `--data` `'{"title":"foobar","body": "This body has both "double" and 'single' quotes"}'`

```
request.get_json()
request.json.get('title')
```

…but I am unable to get it working 
.

Comment: curl -k -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data-binary '{"title":"foobar","body": "This body has both "double" and 'single' quotes"}' -L  X.y.z.w.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/test

Comment: Post your errors as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use proper quoting: you can insert a single quote in a single-quoted string by ending it, putting an escaped quote, and starting a new one.

Here is an example:

```
--data '{"title":"foobar","body": "This body has both "double" and '\''single'\'' quotes"}'
```